# What Roles and Features Are Installed By Default on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows-server-2019

I'm writing some server provisioning automation for some existing servers. I need to know what Windows features are installed by default on a fresh Windows 2019 server so that I know what features I need to install as part of my automation (and so I can test the correct features are getting installed).

Is there a list anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

On a new Windows 2019 Datacenter Core (no UI) image in Azure, these features are installed by default:

```
PS >  Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.Installed } | Format-Table -AutoSize

Display Name                    Name                      Install State
------------                    ----                      -------------
[X] File and Storage Services   FileAndStorage-Services       Installed
    [X] Storage Services        Storage-Services              Installed
[X] .NET Framework 4.7 Features NET-Framework-45-Features     Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 4.7      NET-Framework-45-Core         Installed
    [X] WCF Services            NET-WCF-Services45            Installed
        [X] TCP Port Sharing    NET-WCF-TCP-PortSharing45     Installed
[X] BitLocker Drive Encryption  BitLocker                     Installed
[X] Enhanced Storage            EnhancedStorage               Installed
[X] System Data Archiver        System-DataArchiver           Installed
[X] Windows Defender Antivirus  Windows-Defender              Installed
[X] Windows PowerShell          PowerShellRoot                Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 5.1  PowerShell                    Installed
[X] WoW64 Support               WoW64-Support                 Installed
```

Comment: I assume that is for Server Core, and not with the GUI install. Might want to mention that.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks. Answer edited.